# SOAP service client generated with WSDL configure signing body only

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a client for a web service that I have developed using a Visual Studio service reference via WSDL. It is configured to sign requests with a certificate and can send requests to the service fine, however the service replies with a 400 - Bad Request error, as there is an extra signature in addition to the one I want, with multiple `<Reference>` tags, which uses HMAC-SHA1 as its signature method. The HMAC-SHA1 is unsupported by the web service and as such the request is rejected. However, I don't even want or need this other signature, and I am unsure of where it is coming from. The following is my binding configuration:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="mainBinding">
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
              allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
              requireDerivedKeys="false"
              requireSignatureConfirmation="false"/>
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I also put `ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign` as part of the `ServiceContractAttribute`.

Which part of my configuration is causing the second signature? How can I change the configuration so that I have one signature in my requests?

**EDIT:**

Below is the Request that is sent. In order to highlight the undesirable part I have split it into sections but in reality it is all contiguous.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_1">[removed]</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID u:Id="_2">[removed]</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo u:Id="_3">
            <a:Address>[removed]</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">[removed]</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="[removed]">
                <u:Created>2017-05-11T08:59:25.681Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2017-05-11T09:04:25.681Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <e:EncryptedKey Id="[removed]" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                [removed]
            </e:EncryptedKey>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="[removed]" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">[removed]</o:BinarySecurityToken>
```

**Beginning of part I don't want**

```
            <Signature Id="_0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/> 
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_3">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_4">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="[removed]">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>[removed]</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference URI="[removed]"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
```

**End of part I don't want**

```
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>[removed]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>[removed]</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference URI="[removed]"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        [removed]
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**EDIT 2:**

After some digging and reading I now understand that the two signatures are signatures for the body and the header. I *only* want to sign the body. I've changed the title accordingly.

Comment: How you can do that @Luke (you have 2 Signatures, I only one Signature. Can you show how you config? in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve this myself. I had binding security configured in my app.config but this appears to default to symmetric security, hence the HMAC-SHA1 which uses AES, a symmetric algorithm. Instead of configuring in app.config, I built my own binding using AsymmetricSecurity (shown below). This meant that signatures used RSA, an asymmetric algorithm, instead of AES, and upon doing this the remote server finally accepted the request.

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asbe = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
{
  MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10, // Or WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10 ?
  InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient },
  RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(),
  SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict,
  IncludeTimestamp = true,
  DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15,
  AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true
};
asbe.SetKeyDerivation(false); // What is it for?
asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient });

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.Elements.Add(asbe);
binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement
{
  MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024
});

Client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
```